# Doing a Monte Carlo Analysis of the Birthday Paradox using a HashSet

Tags: java, for-loop, hashset, montecarlo, birthday-paradox

DISCLAIMER : I DO NOT WANT THE ANSWER TO THIS PROBLEM. I SIMPLY NEED SOME GUIDANCE.

I want to perform Monte Carlo analysis on the infamous Birthday Paradox (determining the probability that at least 2 people in a given group share the same birthday) using a `HashSet`.

Now when I run this, the `collisionCount` is WAY lower than I expected it to be.First, I was expecting the `collisionCount` for a group of 10 people to be 11446 (or a probability of 0.11446). Then by the time I got to 100 people, I was expecting the collisionCount to be 100,000 (with a probability of 1.0). But instead, for every 10 people, the collisionCount only counts by 1 (10 people: 1 collision, 20 people: 2 collisions, 30 people: 3 collisions, etc).

Here is the code I have wrote so far :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;


public class BirthdayParadox
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();


    int tests = 100000;
    int collisionCount = 0;

    for(int people = 10; people <= 100; people += 10)
    {
        Set<Integer> birthdays = new HashSet<>(365);
        birthdays.add(rand.nextInt(365));
        for(int runs = 0; runs < tests; runs++)
        {
            int randomBirthday = rand.nextInt(365);

            if(birthdays.contains(randomBirthday))
            {
                collisionCount++;
                break;
            }
            birthdays.add(randomBirthday);
        }
        float prob = (float)collisionCount / tests;

            System.out.println("After " + tests + " tests there were " +
                               collisionCount + " occurrences of shared " +
                               " birthdays in a set of " + people + " people.");
            System.out.println("Probability : " + prob);
    }
  }  
 }
```

---

I guess my question is : Am I not doing something right with either of my for-loops in order to get the `collisionCount` to count correctly?

I am new to learning Java and I am new to the Stack Overflow community and am still learning the ropes. Any help/ advice/ tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you are missing one of your loops.

Notice that your `runs` loop is broken by the first collision. This means that your value will never be more than 1.

Also, you never use your `people` variable inside the inner loop except when outputting results.

What you need to do is run your simulation `100_000` times. The way to do this is to place logic within your `runs` loop that checks if `people` people will have a birthday collision and then iterate your collision count.

Comment: I had a feeling that I needed to do more with my people variable. So you're saying I need to add a third loop within my runs loop (where I somehow implement the people variable) in order to actually get through all 100,000 runs?

Comment: well, no, you need to add another loop to make sure that you actually count all your people. Right now you're doing one run with 100,000 people, if that helps.

Comment: Did you mean 100,000 runs? I thought the outer for-loop would run over no more than 100 people?

Comment: no, what you were doing was trying to get a new birthday 100,000 times and it fails sometime in the first 365 for obvious reasons, leading to a single doublecount.

Comment: Okay so I oughta move that randomBirthday out of that inner for-loop?

Comment: no, it should remain inside. I'll edit my answer to include a few more details, check back in 5 minutes

Comment: @BrandonDusch it has been edited. It should be a little easier

Comment: I tried using a third for loop that would iterate through 10, 20, 30, etc people and that got the runs loop to run 100,000 times. However, the output now shows that there were 100,000 collisions with a set of 10 people going up to 1,000,000 collisions for 100 people. It's supposed to be 11446 collisions for 10 people going up to 100,000 collisions for 100 people. Am I not iterating through the collision count right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the java solution is not the best, this probably it is the problem why you have a difference between the simulation and the mathematical values.  What i understand for the problem is that you have to determine for a group of 10 people (in this case) how many of them share the same birthday. To do that you have to random an array of 10 with number from 0 to 365 (days of the year) and count how many of them are the same. You have to do that severals time (100000 in your case). 
I think that you have to invert the FOR order. I mean..

```
for(int runs = 0; runs < tests; runs++)
{
    //initialize an array of 10
    for(int people = 0; people <= 10; people +=1)
    {
        //random birthdayDay
        //array [people] = rand.nextInt(365);

    }
    //check if there is a collision
    //If there is one you have to increase you success variable in 1   
 }
 //calculate the probability
```

I try to help you, doing kind of pseudocode.
Hope that this help you a little bit.

Regards

Arturo.

Comment: I think `people` is supposed to be a controlled variable

Comment: I think that it is the same in this case, I did some days ago a work using Montecarlo simulation, and i did it in that way. I am not telling that i am correct, but i do not see the mistake doing this in this way.